# When list rendering a component, nested component data doesn't update

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The list rendering on the parent component runs perfectly

```
<stock-card
            class="col-sm"
            v-for="(stock, index) in formattedStocks"
            :stock="stock"
            :key="index"
          >
</stock-card>
```

On the nested component it only renders the first instance of the loop inside the modal component

```
<p class="card-text text-success">{{ stock["name"] }}$</p>
<button
  class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill"
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
  @click="buyStock(stock)"
>
  Activate Modal
</button>
<modal :modalTitle="stock['name']" />
```

I do have props on the both components

Comment: Can you add working example codesandbox where you're facing the issue? There may be some other reason for which list is not rendering.

Comment: Here is the working example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-brattain-8m0lp?file=/src/components/StockCard.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way modal was used.

Generally, bootstrap modal is opened using `data-bs-toggle="modal" and data-bs-target="modalInfo"` attributes. `data-bs-target` is connected with `id="modalInfo"` in order to open and close the model.

In your case, for all three has the same data-bs-target and id, hence it was showing the same first modal in all the cases.

Here is the working example: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-field-xfmu9?file=/src/components/StockCard.vue)